# issues with numerical integration of multi-variable function in R

Tags: r, functional-programming, integration

So, I have this function;

```
f <- function(a, b, q=1, f0=1000) {
#calculate R:
R <- (f0 - (a*b))*((q+1)/(a^(q+1)))
return(ifelse(a<=100,(R * a^q) + b, 0)) }
```

I am using it in another function, funk2

```
funk2 <- function(a,x,b,l,r) {
f(a-x,b) * exp(-(l/r)*(exp(-r*a)*(exp(r*x)-1))) }
```

funk2 is then used to evaluate another multi-variable function funk1 using integration;

```
funk1 <- function(x,b,l,r) {
sapply(x, function (s) {
integrate(funk2, lower = s, upper = s+56, x=s, b=b, l=l, r=r)$value  }) }
```

when I try to evaluate funk1

```
funk1(10,100,1,1)
```

{or by putting any other values} I get an error saying that

```
 Error in integrate(funk2, lower = s, upper = s + 100, x = s, b = b,
 non-finite function value
```

I am not sure what am I doing wrong here? Please help!
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in `f(a-x,b)` inside `funk2` when `a` is equal to `x` then `f(0,b)` will produce `NaN`. For example, if you modify your lower to `lower = s*1.01` you get:

```
funk1(10,100,1,1)
[1] 4464.721
```